# Definition of Limit and Foundational problems.

Tags: category-theory, foundations

I am new to Category theory and I have a quite strong foundational problem.

For example, let's start from the definition of Limit stated by wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28category_theory%29). A limit is an universal cone that satisfies the universal property, i.e. "for each....there exist..." where ALL the variables are not requested to be sets, and consequently they make no sense by a Set-Theoretic point of view.
The same happens every time I use an universal property, or also, for example, in the basic definition of Functor (for each objects...for each morphism...).

I am getting completely stuck and incapable to move on...how can this problem be solved?

Comment: I'm not sure where the set theoretic problem lies. Objects and morphisms are sets. Of course, if you talk about large categories, or whatever, then you have problems expressing the category itself in a set theoretic context, without appealing to universes and so on.

Comment: "Objects and morphisms are sets". Really?
I am sorry, but I completely missed that point!
If it was true, of course the problem should be solved.
Please, could you give me a reference?
(Wikipedia and my book don't say nothing about this).

Comment: And objects and morphisms *are* sets.

Comment: Or, if you want to discuss a specific large category, you can use unbounded quantifiers – just like in the axioms of set theory.

Comment: Again, if you formalize $\cal C$ in set theory, then its objects make a collection definable in the universe of set theory. This means the objects are sets. If you talk about large categories, then you need to ask yourself a question before talking about limits. "How do you formalize large categories in set theory?" (The answer lies in universes, or in some cases, in parameterizations and uniform definitions; but the former is the simpler tool to use and it catches more cases.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: "Again, if you formalize $\cal C$ in set theory, then its objects make a collection definable in the universe of set theory. This means the objects are sets" please, could you be more clear?
For example, I don't understand why, for example, you cannot define a Category with two objects A,B, where A is a set while B a proper class.

Comment: Sure. You can. But now you're running into the nitty-gritty details on how you define a category. If you want the objects to be a *definable collection*, then objects are sets, because only sets are allowed to be elements of other collections. Similarly morphisms are elements of definable classes ($\operatorname{Mor}(A,B)$ or $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$) and therefore must be sets. You ***can***, with universes or with other sort of tricks, define categories which have proper class objects or morphisms. But it will always require "extra care". Which is something often swept under the rug.

Comment: @AsafKaragila very well, so finally the point could be:
1) In the common practice we work with categories whose objects and morphisms are sets (not to be confused with small or locally small categories);
2) In the general case my question has sense and here there is the necessity to put a particular attention.
It could finally works, although I remain a bit worried... :-)
(in my opinion it is an important remark that books should point out)

Comment: @user233650 Well, if you care enough to formalise things in set theory, then you must already secretly believe that every "object" is a set, even if not every collection is a set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: "objects and morphisms are sets." Not really. Perhaps in material set theories such as ZFC this is true, but it is by now pretty clear that ZFC is not the end of the story. Type theory, and more recently homotopy type theory, teach us that it is better to drop the paradigm that everything is a set. There are also more structural set theories such as ETCS (Lawvere) and SEAR (Shulman) in which not everything is a set.

Comment: @Martin: You work in HoTT and I'll interpret it within ZFC (and the appropriate large cardinals needed). Deal? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various foundations of set theory and mathematics which make category theory work. See Shulman's [Set theory for category theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279) for an overview; in fact there is a huge amount of literature on this topic. If you really want to work with [ZFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) or [NBG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) (which is certainly not the best choice!) then a functor $F : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$ consists of two class functions $F_{\mathrm{Ob}} : \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{I}) \to \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and $F_{\mathrm{Mor}} : \mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{I}) \to \mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ satisfying the usual laws. A class function is a class which satisfies the usual definition of a function. In the definition of a limit of a functor, we quantify over functors and therefore over classes. This is not possible in ZFC. But it seems to be possible in NBG.

Notice that you won't run into any set-theoretic difficulties if you don't work with limits of functors, but rather with limits of diagrams as defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633512) for instance. At least, in the definition of a limit, the index category should be assumed to be (essentially) small.

In the comments it has been said that all objects are sets. In ZFC we model our mathematical world that way. In particular, say, Euler's number $e$ is a set. Do we really want this? I think that the paradigm "everything is a set" is outdated since many decades. For more in this, see Leinster's [Rethinking set theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6543) (this is based on Lawvere's [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS)), Shulman's [SEAR](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR), Lawvere's [ETCC](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCC), and Voevodsky's [Homotopy type theory](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/). See also [MO/8731](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8731).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that argument of "how can a real number be a set" is tiresome and silly. Equally silly is the notion that $e$ of $\Bbb R$ and $e$ of $\Bbb R^+$ are not equal, which is what happens in ETCS and the likes of it. Not to mention that if you think about set theory as "the underlying computer" then it makes sense that both numbers and strings end up represented using pulses of electricity and bits of RAM.

Comment: @downvoter: What disturbes you? Didn't I answer the question?

Comment: Thank you, quite interesting answer!