# How to read category diagrams?

Tags: category-theory

I have problems with very basic categorial reasoning.
Suppose we have a commutative "cone" diagram: $f:A \to B$, $g:B \to C$, $h:A \to C$

Is its "commutativity" equivalent of saying: $\forall x\in A \: (g(f(x)) = h(x))$?

If so, 
am I right that a diagram of a couple of parallel functions: $k:A \to B$, $m:A \to B$
does not commute if $k \neq m$

Comment: Yes to all questions. If a diagram commutes, then parallel morphisms in that diagram are equal.

Comment: Caution: f(x) doesn't make sense for morphisms in arbitrary categories! (Unless you interpret it using generalized elements.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you first question is: Yes, unless something different is said, the commutativity of such a diagram means $g\circ f=h$.

For the second part, the answer is usually no, I would say.

I think that there is no universal convention on what commutativity should mean for all possible diagrams. Sometimes one has to guess from the context. If you want to know for a specific article or book you are reading, you should include it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

A usual definition of a diagram (careful, it is not Martin Bandenburg's one) is the following:

> **Definition.** Let $\mathcal J$ be a small category and $\mathcal C$ be a category. A *commutative diagram* of shape $\mathcal J$ in $\mathcal C$ is a functor $\mathcal J \to \mathcal C$.

So, writting a diagram in the naive sense (a bunch of objects and arrows between them) in $\mathcal C$ and declare it commutative is not enough: one needs to specify the *index category* $\mathcal J$.

Let me explain why. A "naive diagram" in $\mathcal C$ like
$$ A \overset f {\underset g\rightrightarrows} B$$
could be a commutative diagram $D_0 \colon \mathcal J_0 \to \mathcal C$ or $D_1\colon \mathcal J_1 \to \mathcal C$ where

- $\mathcal J_0$ is the category with objects $0,1$ and two distinct morphisms $i_0,i_1 \colon 0 \to 1$ (plus the identities); composition is the only possible one ; $\mathcal D_0$ then acts by
  $$ 0 \mapsto A,\, 1\mapsto B,\, i_0 \mapsto f,\, i_1\mapsto g$$
- $\mathcal J_1$ is the category with objects $0,1,2$ and three  morphisms $i\colon 0\to 1,j \colon 1 \to 2, k\colon 0 \to 2$ (plus the identities) ; composition is the only one in which $k=ji$ ; and let $\mathcal D_1$ act by
  $$ 0 \mapsto A,\, 1\mapsto A,\, 2 \mapsto B,\, i \mapsto \mathrm{id}_A,\, j\mapsto f, k\mapsto g$$

In the first case, the commutativity of the diagram does not implies $f=g$ (it is possible though). In the second case, the commutativity ensures $f=g$.

When the situation is ambiguous, just refer to the index category!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633512) for a general, precise definition of a commutative diagram. It follows readily that a triangle

$$\begin{array}{cc} & B & \\ ~~~f\nearrow && \searrow g~~~~\\A & \underset{\large h}{\longrightarrow} & \overset{\phantom{-}}{B} \end{array}$$

commutes iff $h = g \circ f$, and that a diagram of two parallel morphisms

$$A~ \overset{\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}}{\underset{g}{\longrightarrow}} ~B$$

commutes iff $f=g$.

Comment: I think you should emphasize what you said earlier in a comment: it does *not* necessarily mean that $\forall x\in A \: (g(f(x)) = h(x))$. You might bring up the category of propositions and proofs, for example, or poset categories.

Comment: It depends on the meaning of $x \in A$. You have to interpret it as a morphism $x : T \to A$.

Comment: You can do that if the category has a terminal object, certainly, but I doubt that was what OP meant by the question.

Comment: i understand that $\in$ is not necessarily applicable in general case, neither is "functional notation". but, how to determine the "boundary"? in many cases authors switch to "g(f(x))=h(x)" statements -- how to tell if it was a legitimate move? why do you think that it is not legitimate for Poset?

Comment: @MJD: No need for terminal objects. $T$ should be arbitrary! Look for "generalized element".

Comment: Why the downvote?