# Morphisms in a commutative diagram

Tags: category-theory

I'm studying category theory as a hobby. I'm at a beginner level.
I have a simple question:
Suppose we have a commutative diagram.
In it there are two objects A,B and exist 2 morphisms from A to B and from B to A. Is it true that the two objects are isomorphic?
(And the reason is that in a commutative diagram the only endomorphisms are the identity morphisms)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, draw the commutative diagram, because as it is, this question is unclear.

Comment: Do you mean: exactly one arrow from $A$ to $B$ and exactly one from $B$ to $A$?

Comment: @crostul  I think that the only things that is important to know is that there are 2 objects and 2 morphism from each other. The diagram isn't essential.

Comment: @drhab  Yes, the are exactly one arrow in each direction

Comment: "in a commutative diagram the only endomorphisms are the identity morphisms" : not at all!

Comment: There is no reason for the objects to be isomorphic. A diagram may certainly contain non-identity morphisms.

Comment: Then I think that the answer to your question is "yes". A [commutative diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram#Diagrams_as_functors) is indexed by a poset category. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/633512/75923) is a related question.

Comment: @paf  As I said I am a beginner... maybe I didn't understood what is a commutative diagram. In a commutative diagram the paths that connects two objects must be equal (morphism composition). If this is true each path that starts and ends at the same object must be equal to the identity morphism.

Comment: @IttayWeiss A diagram, yes. But also a commutative diagram? Then it cannot be indexed by a poset.

Comment: Your remark that in a commutative diagram the only endomorphisms are the identity morphisms is too shortsighted. Observe that $A\stackrel{f}{\to}A$ denotes a commutative diagram for every endomorphism $f$. Btw, as a beginner on this you posed a very good question.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the diagram $f\colon A\rightleftarrows B\colon g$. There are four commutativity conditions one could impose.

1. No conditions
2. $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_A$, i.e. $A\xleftarrow{g}B$ is a left inverse (also known as a **retraction**) of $X\xrightarrow{f}Y$.
3. $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_B$, i.e. $A\xleftarrow{g}B$ is a right inverse (also known as a **section**) of $A\xrightarrow{f}B$.
4. Both $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_A$ and $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_B$, i.e. $g$ and $f$ are inverses of one another and are therefore **isomorphisms**.

The "standard" definition of commutative diagram, that for any two objects, any two paths of composable morphisms compose to the same thing, coincides with the commutativity condition 4. (since the empty path composes to the identity morphism).

But in practice you often want to (and books and papers often do) express one of the weaker conditions 1., 2., 3., or perhaps even some other condition ($(g\circ f)\circ(g\circ f)=g\circ f$, for example). To accommodate such usage, it is more useful to think not of commutative diagrams, but of diagrams with imposed commutativity relations, where the commutativity relations are usually left implicit but can be figured out from the context in which the diagram appears.

A concrete example is the diagram $X\to Y\rightrightarrows Z$ of an equalizer of two morphisms. Here the implicit commutativity relation is that any two *maximal* paths of composable morphisms compose to the same morphism (otherwise, the standard definition of commutative diagram wold force the parallel morphisms $Y\rightrightarrows Z$ to be the same morphism).

Answer (score 1):

If the following diagram is said to be a [**commutative diagram**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+diagram)
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \leftrightarrows & B\end{array}

then the two pictured arrows are indeed isomorphisms.

In this diagram there are at most $4$ arrows involved: the two pictured arrows and next to that also the non-pictured identities. Essential for commutative diagram: **parallel arrows are equal**.

If $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ then $\text{id}_A$ and $g\circ f$ are parallel so that the conclusion $\text{id}_A=g\circ f$ is justified. Likewise $\text{id}_B=f\circ g$.

For a broader treatment of commutative diagrams have a look at [Grothendiecks Tohoku paper](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/gk.pdf) on the pages 10 and 11.