# Isn't "diagram" a misnomer in regards to the standard definition of being a functor $D : J \to C$?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, function-and-relation-composition, functors, diagram-chasing

[Definition of diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_(category_theory)#Definition).  When you draw an actual, what I call "diagram" on paper, it may have:

- Duplicated objects and arrows which is still valid.
- You don't always put in the compositions, as that would make displaying the diagram impossible sometimes.
- In the subclass *commutative diagrams*, you can't even always compose and retain commutativity.

To see the last point, draw something that commutes, and then draw an arrow connecting to the diagram like a hair (the compositions aren't filled in, and only one end of the arrow meets the first diagram).  So, even though that diagram commutes between any two paths sharing domain/codomain, you can't always fill in all compositions!

> Thus, how should we define "drawn diagrams" formally, in order to distinguish them from the functor definition?

I think it would help out the theory a bit, since once you define drawn diagrams, you can define their basic properties.  It is important for my work on BananaCats to make this distinction, since diagram drawing is a big part of the app.

---

In other words, the definition of *drawn diagram* should have a 1-1 correspondence with the items drawn on a canvas, where items are either: arrow, object, each of which has a label, and such that two distinct items are not equal when their labels are, though they map to a category in which the two items are equal.

---

Something like this:

A **drawn diagram** in the category $C$ is a directed, labeled graph $G = (E, V)$ and a map $F : E \cup V \to \text{hom}(C) \cup \text{ob}(C)$ such that if $f : u \to v$ is an edge in $G$, then $F(f) : F(u) \to F(v)$ in $C$.

A **commutative drawn diagram** in a category $C$ is a drawn diagram such that whenever $u_1 = v_1$, $u_n = v_m$, and $f := u_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} \cdots \xrightarrow{f_n} u_n$ and $g := v_1 \xrightarrow{g_1} \dots \xrightarrow{g_n} v_m$ are paths in $G$ then $\bigcirc_{i=1}^n F(f_i) = \bigcirc_{i=1}^m F(g_i)$.

Comment: If you are coding an app for drawing diagrams, then isn't the definition of diagram something you can do as you see fit. In other words, I see this more as a question on software design as opposed to math.

Comment: The definition of drawn diagram is reasonable I think. You probably want to require that one of the paths has length longer than 1 in the commutative drawn diagram case, because two parallel arrows (e.g. in equalizers/coequalizers) should not require equality of the parallel arrows, just the composites involving them.

Comment: There's a free category functor on directed multigraphs, so that directed multigraph homomorphisms from a graph $D$ to the objects and morphisms of a category $\mathcal{C}$ correspond to functors from the free category on $D$ to $\mathcal{C}$; commutative diagrams are functors from a particular quotient on the free category. So the "drawn diagram" idea is just focusing on the graph half of this free/forgetful adjunction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it's better to follow standard practices when coding and especially match your structures to what is defined formally in math.  The question applies to math because every time a new student reads a diagram there is an intutive feeling that something's not being addressed with regards to drawn vs. functor diagram.  Also there should be more books on diagram rules themselves, such as tricks you can do to prove a diagram is commutative without exhaustively proving every possible path.  Surely, these books would bring up the distinction between drawing and the functor abstraction.

Comment: @jgon hmm... that is a problem.  Alternatively, just say that it commutes except at the subdiagram of the two parallel arrows.  It would be more awkward in the general context of diagram chasing to omit the case of parallel arrows just for the sake of a few particular definitions that includes equalizers.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine The drawn diagram does not necc. just focus on the graph half.  After all there is the connection to the category side given by the multigraph hom into $C$.  Now on you can prove stuff about drawn diagrams using category theory or about category theory using drawn diagrams (which is what's already done!).  So to say that the "drawn diagram" is just focusing on the graph half, is completely incorrect seeming to me.  Any decent book on categories will encourage the user to draw diagrams to reason about cats.  Hence they are not focused on graphs.

Comment: All I'm saying is that *drawn diagrams* are a language on there own, one that can / should be formalized further, for the sake of proving things in the language, which is already being done, except without much rigor (no books on drawing diagrams and formally connecting them to the rest of cat theory).  And I've seen many questions on MSE that bring up my doubts about my own understanding of what the drawn diagram means.  Lastly, when was the last time we thought about a diagram functor when reasoning about a particular diagram.  I personally, never have used the *diagram functor* explicitly.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633512/what-is-the-definition-of-a-commutative-diagram) might be of interest.